# Is a "PhD by prior publication" recognized the same as a conventional one?

Tags: publications, phd

A "PhD by (prior) publication" is an alternative way of pursuing a doctoral degree, where the degree is awarded based on a portfolio/collection of (related) papers that the candidate has published in peer-reviewed journals. This approach seems to be more common in Australia and the UK, but even then it still is not very widespread (according to Times Higher Education, only 1 out of 3 UK universities offered such opportunities). Is a degree obtained in this way just as legitimate, and does it hold the same value and recognition in other countries (I am mainly interested in the EU and Canada, but not only) as a conventional PhD?

- Legal: Would it pass the "recognition of a degree obtained abroad" procedures?
- Perception: Does it hold the same perceived value for the people who will be evaluating the CV later on?

Comment: Would someone looking over the CV have any way to know that it was a PhD by prior publication? If the person has publications in non-predatory peer-reviewed journals, does that not indicate that they know how to perform research?

Comment: Recognized where, exactly?

Comment: " 1 out of 3 UK universities offered such opportunities" I strongly suspect that is not true.  Usually such things are decided by the thesis examiners, not the university.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist ... "Usually such things are decided by the thesis examiners, not the university"  The university decides whether such a thing is possible at all.  If it is allowed, next the advisor would have to agree.  And only then the thesis examiners would be involved.

Comment: @GEdgar I think that's mostly false.  "The university" does not read the thesis or regulate its contents in detail.  I really doubt there is a university that forbids, university-wide, a thesis that is a portfolio of published work.

Comment: Perhaps there's some ambiguity in the question: "PhD by prior whatever" might mean _not_ doing the usual coursework requirements, preliminary exams, etc. In the U.S., in my experience, most universities like to have lots of control over credit hours (even at the graduate level), tuition being paid, etc., and would not permit a dept to aware a PhD without doing all those things. I think that's @GEdgar's point. On the opposite hand, sure, the stuff _for_the_thesis_ could have had its origins prior to enrollment, sure. :)

Answer (score 8):

Nobody will care in which way you obtained your PhD, as long as you obtained your PhD. There is no legal difference, and in all likelihood, very few people will ever look up your PhD thesis to actually find out. All that matters is that you have the three letters; nothing else is of importance.

Answer (score 2):

From a legal perspective, I see no reason that legal recognition of a degree would distinguish between a PhD that included a dissertation and one that was done by publication.  In both cases there is an award of the same degree, and the distinction is purely internal to the university.  To the extent that a legal process would inquire into this, it would be solely at the accreditation level --- i.e., there may be processes by which the State reviews and awards accreditation to universities that recognise their degree programs.

As to the perceived value, there are two things to bear in mind.  Firstly, people will typically not even know which you did; perceived value of a PhD degree in academia is usually a superficial assessment made based on the institution that awarded it (perhaps also the supervisor) and people would hardly ever bother making any inquiry into the content of your PhD program, dissertation, etc.  In your CV you will state that you have a PhD degree in field X from university Y awarded in year Z.  That is all the information that people will have and I have never heard of any member of a selection panel, etc., ever asking for more information on content.  Secondly, even if a person were to inquire about the content of your program, the primary purpose of a PhD program is to teach a person to do scholarly research, and a PhD by publication demonstrates this at least as well as a PhD by dissertation.  Most people who scrutinise your academic CV will care more about your publications than your PhD degree, precisely because the publications are the best evidence of your ability to do scholarly research.  *Ceteris paribus* (particularly with the same publication record), it is unlikely that one option would be perceived as better or worse than the other.

Comment: why the downvotes?  This seems like a perfectly acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2):

What matters for "acceptance" of a degree is not how it was achieved, but the fact that it was awarded by an accredited (for doctoral education) institution. If they call it a PhD and are certified by appropriate agencies to award PhDs then it "is" a PhD and it would be extremely rare for anyone to question it.

It is possible, in fact, for an independent researcher without a doctorate to do seminal work, perhaps in a new field, and only then apply for a degree. If the university judges the work as "equivalent" to a dissertation then they might award the degree, depending on their rules.

So, people in general with few exceptions, will defer to the university and the judgement of its faculty. The precise nature of the doctoral work and any dissertation is secondary.

Note, however, that the system isn't perfect. Some dissertations are garbage, even fraudulent. Even Einstein's doctoral dissertation was a very minor work compared to Special Relativity, though they occurred in the same year.

The exception, of course, is "honorary" doctorates, but those are marked as such and usually given for things other than doctoral level research. But you don't seem to be asking about such things.

Answer (score 0):

"Sandwich theses" are quite common in some domains, usually ones where students are expected to publish during their PhD. They hold exactly the same value as classic theses in institutions that allow them (most places that I know) and are only distinguishable by looking at the content.

One remark: personally, they annoy me. As an external, it is difficult to do anything with a sandwich thesis.. I have quite a few times found stuff that I was not quite happy with in a proof or numerical work. However, if the work is a published paper, then I don't feel comfortable criticizing something that has made it through peer review unless there is a major mistake. I am an external twice a year on average and most of my recent evaluations have been of sandwich theses. I understand the appeal to students (and by extension to supervisors), but I wish I saw more of the classic theses, where I really feel that my role as external can make a difference.

Comment: A "sandwich thesis" isn't a "PhD by publication".

Comment: @BryanKrause I think that rather depends on the context. I've heard both "sandwich thesis" and "PhD by publication" to refer to same thing: graduating based on a thesis which is just a collection of published work, as-is, with an addition of intro+conclusion chapters. The answer doesn't, however, address "PhD by _prior_ publication" (which, to my understanding, would mean you are awarded a PhD based on research done outside of formal PhD studies).

Comment: @penelope I disagree, they're quite distinct. A PhD by publication suggests you've not been officially enrolled in a program during your studies and are getting the degree for what you publish. A stapler thesis is just a thesis format. No matter what you aren't getting a PhD for your thesis document, you're getting it for the research it contains whatever the format.

Comment: At least in the circles I'm in, I've heard the terms "sandwich thesis" and "PhD by publication" used interchangeably; in both cases the person was enrolled into a PhD programme while the research was being conducted. On the other hand, "PhD by prior publication" is different, and suggests, as you say, that the research has been conducted outside of a PhD programme.